# How do I convert strings like "<br><br><br><br><br><br>" to "<br>" using java's String.replaceAll(String, String) method?

Tags: java, regex, string

how to convert string

```
"<br><br><br><br><br><br>" to 
"<br>" using java's String.replaceAll(String, String) method?
```

I've tried both:

```
    str.replaceAll("<br>+","<br>");
    str.replaceAll("<br>{1,}","<br>);
```

but neither work.

Comment: why did you think those would work? they just replace every occurence of <br> by another one.

Comment: @shingetsu: he is working with regular expressions and he is close

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<br>+` matches `"<br>>>>>>>>"`, try this instead: `(<br>)+`

And if there are spaces in between the tags, do:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(<br>\\s*)+","<br>");
```